# how to find out which ioports be assigned to my devices

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, x86-64, ioports

has linux reserved io port numbers for all manufactured devices.

I have devices like intel built-in network card. or another device I have for wifi (usb) from realtek.
On linux repository on github, device drivers use specific io ports to register. And kernel assign those ports to device driver. device drivers normally request for ports using call to request_region function. so for some ethernet device it requests like following

```
    for (id_port = 0x110 ; id_port < 0x200; id_port += 0x10)
     {
    if (!request_region(id_port, 1, "3c509-control")) 
    continue;
    outb(0x00, id_port);
    outb(0xff, id_port);
    if (inb(id_port) & 0x01)
    break;
    else
    release_region(id_port, 1);
    }
```

above starts with `0x110` to `0x200`, any port can be assigned in this range by kernel to driver and appear in /proc/ioports file means driver is using that io port by the time of success return from `request_region`.

Question : So my question is has linux assigned io ports to all manufactured devices usable with kernel 5.7 or latest kernel version?

Question : What if I want to write device driver for any device. How can I find the io ports number range to request to. I dont not expect that I have to look into kernel code and find similer driver port range. so How can I find that io port number range. how to achieve this first step required in writing device driver (any device. be it wifi internet device or ethernet device)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791626/1216776

Comment: You're misunderstanding the purpose of **request_region()**.  First, Linux does not  *"assign those ports"*.  Devices use I/O port numbers that are hardwired or configured by BIOS or switches or ???, but not *"assign"* by the kernel.  Device drivers must be informed of what I/O ports or memory addresses to use to access the device.   The driver then uses **request_region()** (or  **request_mem_region()**) to claim exclusive use of those addresses.  IOW it is resource management to prevent driver conflicts.

Comment: *"How can I find the io ports number range ..."* -- That is a thorny problem that is supposed to be solved by the plug-and-play initiatives (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_Plug_and_Play), PCI/PCIe, Device Tree, a probe() routine in the driver, ACPI, etc.

Comment: @Alex: As per the other question, you have a very deep misunderstanding, what I/O ports are actually all about. You've latched onto some very weird misunderstanding of what they are, and what they do. I think before you continue this avenue of questions (which actually is quite good), you seriously need to polish up your knowledge about what an I/O port actually is, how it is not related at all to networking (I got the feeling you're cofusing it with TCP/IP ports).

Comment: @datenwolf u really think that I am considering tcp in anyway. what way exactly? TCP ports are totally different.

Comment: @datenwolf What I understood is IO ports mapped with memory address space in computer memory. They should be if we are talking about `x86` or `x86-64`. What I am confused about is how io port `number address` is mapped to memory address. I means there has to be some `number address` which get mapped to similar number address in computer memory in the first place. how to get that `number address` for some xyz Ethernet device.

Comment: @datenwolf this is really I am trying to find. First finding what is my Ethernet device is with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz` or which ever I am using as Ethernet device. then find what address is mapped to  which memory before calling request_region function then call request_region with that number address to secure the address and use it as in my device driver to get packets from Ethernet device and forward up the stack

Comment: @Alex: If it's USB: then it doesn't have a memory address assigned. It sits somewhere on the USB bus, and you're talking to it through USB transactions. If it's a Ethernet device connected to PCI or PCIe, you're getting a BAR (a Base Address Register) and therein you find the information which memory range it occupies. I/O ports are legacy. Unless you have an old ISA card you don't deal with it.

Comment: @Alex: And I doubt it, that you have an old style ISA Ethernet card connected to a CPU that's been made in the past 10 years. Heck, even if you were using some industrial "keep the lights on" motherboard with ISA slots (which BTW often are not fully compatible), you'd not plug an ISA style network card in there.

Comment: @datenwolf `If it's a Ethernet device connected to PCI or PCIe, you're getting a BAR (a Base Address Register) and therein you find the information which memory range it occupies.` 
How on Linux I can get BAR for my Ethernet device. So I can start working on driver creation. Please tell. All I want is that a `Base Address Register` range so I can use it in my `request_region` call in `__init` of my driver (it should be called from __int, right?)

Comment: @Alex: Is it actually a PCI device? Because in the previous quesiton you were mentioning USB. For what's it worth. You're using the PCI support library (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/pci/pci.html), use `__pci_register_driver` to register your module, then the kernel will call the `probe` function you registered with the information to access the BAR, which you use with `pci_request_regions` to enable the mappings.

Comment: @datenwolf make sense thank you very much. u really help me out. thanks

Comment: @datenwolf BTW what type of driver are used with built-in NIC card of 11th generation Intel computers or whichever is latest? I am talking or i7 or more newer versions of Intel computers if there are any more newer?

Comment: @Alex: That depends on what the mainboard manufacturer chose. But popular choices these days are Intel e1000 or Realtek RTL81xx based NICs. But it's really up to the maker of the mainboard.

Comment: @Alex: If you're interested in the driver for Intel NICs those are located here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/ethernet/intel – as you can see, that's a massive amount of code. The piece of code that does the whole PCI probing and mapping is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3516bd729358a2a9b090c1905bd2a3fa926e24c6/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L2814

Comment: @datenwolf so most latest drivers are `PCI` based means they do PCI probing or pci probing is somehow involved like u said `You're using the PCI support library (kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/pci/pci.html), use __pci_register_driver to register your module, then the kernel will call the probe function you registered with the information to access the BAR, which you use with pci_request_regions to enable the mappings`
and
`The piece of code that does the whole PCI probing and mapping is here`

Comment: @Alex: It's not just that the drivers are "PCI" based. If the device the driver is written for is a PCI device, it must use PCI functions, obviously. If it's a USB device, an entirely different set of functions is used, the USB API https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/index.html – first and foremost you *must* know your device first.

Comment: @datenwolf can u please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990043/setting-device-interrupt-register-to-0-not-causing-any-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question : So my question is has linux assigned io ports to all manufactured devices usable with kernel 5.7 or latest kernel version?

No.

> Question : What if I want to write device driver for any device. How can I find the io ports number range to request to.

You ask the user for it. After all it's the user who set them using jumpers on the ISA card.

Here's a picture of an old Sound Blaster card (taken from Wikipedia, I'm too lazy to rummage around in my basement now). I've highlighted a specific area in the picture:

[image: Sound Blaster card with port jumper highlighted]

That jumper header I highlighted: That's the port configuration jumper. As a user you literally connect two of the pins with a jumper connector and that connects a specific address line that comes from the card connectors to the circuitry on the rest of the card. This address line is part of the AT bus port I/O scheme. The user sets this jumper, writes down the number and then tells the driver, which number it was set to. That's how AT style I/O ports.

Or the driver uses one of the well known port numbers for specific hardware (like network controllers) that dates back to the era, where ISA style ports were still are thing. Also there's old ISA-P'n'P where the BIOS and the add-in cards would negotiate the port assignments at power up, before the OS even started. You can read those port numbers with the ISA-P'n'P API provided by the kernel.

**We no longer use this kind of hardware in practice!** Except for legacy and retro computing purposes.

Over a quarter of century ago, the old AT / ISA bus was superseeded with PCI. Today we use PCIe which, from the point of view of software still looks like PCI. One of the important things about PCI was, that it completely dropped the whole concept of ports.

With ISA what you had were 8 data lines and 16 address lines, plus two read/write enable lines, one for memory mapped I/O and one for port I/O. You can find the details here [https://archive.is/3jjZj](https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/buses/isa/). But what happens when you're reading from say, port 0x0104, it would physically set the bit pattern of 0x0104 to the address lines on the ISA bus, pull low the read enable line, and then read the voltage level on the data lines. And all of that is implemented as an actual set of instructions of the x86: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_139.html

Now look at the PCI bus: There's no longer separate data and address lines. Instead read/write commands would be sent, and everything happens through memory mappings. PCI devices have something called a BAR: a *Base Address Register*. This is configured by the PCI root complex and assigns the hardware the region of actual physical bus addresses where it appears. The OS has to get those BAR information from the PCI root complex. The driver uses the PCI IDs to have the hardware discovered and the BAR information told to it. It can then do memory reads/writes to talk to the hardware. No I/O ports involved. And that is just the lowest level. USB and Ethernet happen a lot further up. USB is quite abstract, as is Ethernet.

Your other question [Looking for driver developer datasheet of Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537802/looking-for-driver-developer-datasheet-of-intelr-coretm-i5-2450m-cpu-2-50g) suggests, that you have some serious misconceptions of what is actually going on. You were asking about USB devices, and Ethernet ports. Neither of those in any way directly interact with this part of the computer.

Your question per se is interesting. But we're also running into a massive XYZ problem here; it's worse than an XY problem; you're asking about X, although you want to solve Y. But Y isn't even the problem you're dealing with in the first place.

You're obviously smart, and curious, and I applaud that. But I have to tell you, that you've to backtrack quite a bit, to clear up some of the misconceptions you have.

Comment: `You ask the user for it. After all it's the user who set them using jumpers on the ISA card.` 
I am the user of my computer. I should I get io ports or BAR (which ever it is called) on Linux?

Comment: @Alex: Please get this. Ports as you're seeing them in the 3c509 source code you're constantly referring to *DO NOT EXIST ANYMORE(!)*. You're barking up an entirely wrong tree (which as a matter of fact is a stalk of bamboo). You're trying to do something, that doesn't even apply in your particular case. You've been asking about a USB device. USB devices *don't use ports*, and they don't use memory mapping as well.

Comment: @Alex: Please, just to keep the sanity of everyone who's participating here: Please tell us, what it it really is what you're trying to do. You want to write a driver, okay, we get that. But why do you want to write that driver in the first place. What piece of hardware are you working with, that needs a driver. Why do you want to use that piece of hardware. –– For some reason you're so hung up on the configuration of lowest of low level stuff, without having an actual idea, what the stuff down there actually does.

Comment: @Alex: Please answer the following: What is your project *all* about. What's it, that you want to do once you've written the driver, and all the other things that go along with it. What is it, that you're really trying to do.

Comment: basically I have a NIC card built-in in my computer. And I was also reading `Linux Device Driver`. So I like to make a driver to communicate with my internet/NIC card (for learning purposes). So I was reading the book and in io chapter it says I need the io port that is basically an address that is mapped to computer memory (in x86-64). so I was looking into what exactly I need for my driver to make it communicate with my network card built in inside my computer.

Comment: So I most likely need to know is there any things like BAR (which there is. and mentioned in book). So That what I want is . having some memory address or call it BAR or ioports or anything. its just make sense. your answer making pretty much sense which is kind of supporting the book views of driver development plus what I found on the internet. How to make my driver communicate with device (which is NIC card or Ethernet card or Network card connected -- same and NOT USB device)

Comment: @Alex: Yes, but you still need to answer the question: What is it you really want to do. –– Do you want to just Implement a driver for that Ethernet card? If so, do you have the documentation required for that? You'll need documentation on how the NIC lays out its configuration register space, what each bit of each register means. And when you've done that, you'll still have to implement the whole Ethernet frame packet transfer, and tie it to user space. –– What is it, that you want to do with that card.

Comment: @Alex: As I see it, you want to do something with that card. What is it? –– If there's documentation for that card available (which you absolutely need to write a driver), then Linux for sure already has drivers for it: The general case with Linux is, if hardware has publicly available documentation, there already Linux drivers for it available, usually as part of the main kernel soruce tree.

Comment: `If so, do you have the documentation required for that? You'll need documentation on how the NIC lays out its configuration register space, what each bit of each register means.` 
First how on linux I can get some useful info about my NIC card to use in my search on google for documentation that covers `on how the NIC lays out its configuration register space, what each bit of each register means.`

Comment: You figure out what Ethernet card you're using in the first place. You could for example do a `lspci -nn | grep -i net`, that tells you the vendor and make of the network cards you have. From there on it's using a lot of Google, to sift through the webpages of the vendors. You may also try to navigate the vendor website yourself. For example when you type "e1000 reference datasheet NIC Intel 8086 15a1 e1000" into Google and carefully look through the results you'll get this: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/82576eg-gbe-datasheet.pdf

Comment: It's an overstatement that computers don't have I/O ports anymore.  PCI still includes I/O address space.  x86 can read/write it with `in`/`out` instructions.  They're slow so modern devices (unlike some classic https://wiki.osdev.org/Ethernet_devices) typically only use MMIO, but *computers* include a few legacy I/O port addresses that still do things, some non-emulated ones.  `lspci -v` output on my Skylake Z170 mobo includes Intel AHCI SATA with `I/O ports at f090 [size=8]` and 2 other blocks, as well as the "memory" blocks where the main stuff goes.  And VGA has a handful of I/O ports.

Comment: You're 100% correct that writing a driver for a USB device will have nothing to do with I/O ports, though!  Not even MMIO registers registers like a PCI device, so probably you'd want `lsusb` (maybe with `-v`) to find out what kind of USB device you have.

Comment: `cat /proc/ioports` on my system includes some real drivers that claim and probably actually use I/O ports, like i801_smbus, and some ACPI stuff.  Not just real legacy stuff like PS/2 keyboard, and legacy interfaces that have other ways to do the same things (PIC instead of APIC)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Rest assured, that these I/O ports only exist through some legacy-compatibility trickery through the LPC interface (LPC = low pin count), or eSPI that's connected through a host interface to the host bus, see https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/program/design/us/en/documents/low-pin-count-interface-specification.pdf p.11 ff. – details on eSPI on current Intel chipsets file:///tmp/mozilla_dw0/631119-004.pdf p.77 ff. – That together with some SMM code trickery will emulate I/O ports operations using that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: And yes, PCI devices also can "listen" to I/O "ports". But strictly speaking. I/O *ports* only existed on the old AT / ISA bus, and everything you're seeing today on your computer is just smoke and mirrors (unless it's a system with an actual, true ISA bus, directly supported by the CPU south bridge; PCI→ISA bridges usually lack much of the functionality, which is why legacy ISA boards still sell well on eBay).

Comment: @datenwolf: SMM emulation of a whole legacy device is one thing, and yeah totally smoke & mirrors.  But either I'm misunderstanding or you're applying that term over-broadly:  `in` and `out` instructions to some port numbers can access I/O space without trapping to SMM mode to send the PCI(e) IO-space message, if there's real hardware (like an NE2000 PCI card), right?  Obviously the physical / electrical details are different from ISA, and yeah some hardware is behind an LPC serial link or something, not on the PCI /  PCIe bus itself, but IMO that's not just smoke.

Comment: Or are you insisting on a big distinction between PCI IO space vs. ISA IO "ports"?  From a software PoV there isn't an important distinction: running an `in` instruction does off-chip I/O without trapping into SMM mode (for some addresses), so PCI IO space is just how port-IO instructions work on modern x86.  Speed differences between on-chip vs. off-chip ports are also measurable; IIRC someone (maybe Margaret Bloom) did some bare-metal testing of VGA vs. PIC port numbers...   The manual still describes https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in as "Input byte from imm8 I/O port address into AL"

Comment: @datenwolf I have asked another question on pci driver. can u please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576609/does-pci-driver-functions-represented-as-function-number-in-pcis-driver-data-ob