# Does pci driver functions represented as function number in PCI's driver_data object

Tags: linux, driver, kernel-module, ethernet, pci

Does Each PCI peripheral function (from Linux Device Driver -- Book `Each PCI periphel is identified by a bus number, a device number, and a function number.`) specified as a pci driver data? (Question: is net_device a driver function in pci_dev  **as a network function**)  as assigning in

```
  net_device dev
  pci_dev pdev
  ....
  ....
  pci_set_drvdata (pdev, dev);
```

the above code is present in Linux's RealTek Ethernet driver's pci
device driver's probe function from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3516bd729358a2a9b090c1905bd2a3fa926e24c6/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c

Comment: if so, Can there be more than one function in pci driver?

Comment: You mixed several things in one question / topic. There are: a) **physical bus** the device is connected by; b) **function** (s) of the device independently of the **physical bus**; c) Linux kernel **device model** and device representation in it; d) Linux kernel **bus representation** for a **physical bus**; e) Linux kernel **framework** (s) to drive a specific **function** of the physical device; f) PCI complaint device and functions.