# Setting device interrupt register to 0 not causing any result

Tags: linux, io, driver, intel, pci

I created small c code to disable Ethernet card device driver's poll interrupt handler on device settings. But its not causing  my ethernet card to stop receiving packets. Why is that?
This is the code

```
    #include <sys/io.h>

    #include <linux/if_ether.h>
    #include <net/ethernet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <netinet/tcp.h>
    #include <netinet/ip.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    void main(){
        unsigned long addr;
        void *data=0x00;//malloc(sizeof(struct ether_header)+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));
        addr=0x00000000fe400000+0x000C8;
        int x=iopl(3);
        outsb(addr,&data,sizeof(data));


    }
```

Base addres that I am using in code `0x00000000fe400000`
I check clearing interrupt at ofset `0x000C0` and `0x000C8`
Other options are:

1. 0x000C0=Interrupt Cause Read Register
2. 0x000C4=Interrupt Throttling Register
3. 0x000C8=Interrupt Cause Set Register
4. 0x000D0=Interrupt Mask Set/Read Register
5. 0x000D8=Interrupt Mask Clear Register
6. 0x000E0=Interrupt Acknowledge Auto

Device Specification: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
(Lewisville) (rev 04)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN

lspci -vvv

> Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
> DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
> Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection >(Lewisville)
> Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-
> Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
> Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort-
> <TAbort- SERR- <PERR- INTx-
> Latency: 0
> Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 29
> Region 0: Memory at fe400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
> Region 1: Memory at fe427000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
> Region 2: I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
> Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
> Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA
> PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
> Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
> Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
> Address: 00000000fee08004  Data: 4023
> Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
> AFCap: TP+ FLR+
> AFCtrl: FLR-
> AFStatus: TP-
> Kernel driver in use: e1000e
> Kernel modules: e1000e

Comment: iopl(3) returning 0

Comment: Are you sure it's old school I/O and not memory mapped I/O? `/dev/mem` (and devmem utility) might be the answer for quick hacks if it's actually memory mapped. Is it mapped to this address on your PC?

Comment: @domen my port is memory mapped but I am directly accessing it at the base address plus offset. I am disabling interrupt but not working

Comment: If your port is memory mapped, you can't use `outsb`, you need a plain store instruction (e.g. a store to a  `volatile char*`)

Comment: @PeterCordes do u mean assign address to `volatile char *` and just write to it?

Comment: Yeah, that's how MMIO works (PCIe memory space), as opposed to port IO (PCIe io space).

Comment: @PeterCordes in code is dev/mem a address to base `0x00000000fe40000` in question or overall address for all devices?

Comment: You have to mmap the physical MMIO region into your process at some virtual address, and then use that virtual address.  Typically by doing `mmap` on `/dev/mem`, I think; it's not something I've done.  Even as root you might need to override some safety settings to let you do this from user-space.  (Like CAP_SYS_RAWIO, as shown in [Is memory mapped I/O only used internally by OS, not exposed to and used by programmers on top of Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475805) shows mmap of /dev/mem, casting the resulting pointer to `volatile*`)

Comment: @PeterCordes how to set `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` is it same as iopl(3)?

Comment: I don't know, but I bet google does.  I just said it's not something I've ever done.  I think you need `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` for `iopl()` to work, or something like that.

Comment: Simplest is to just be root, who has all the capabilities. Proper way would be something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-to-replace-setuid-with-file-system-capabilities Although it's probably not any more secure, since accessing `/dev/mem` can give you root anyway. You might need to recompile Linux kernel to have driver for `/dev/mem` enabled - it can be useful for HW development, but it's basically a security hole.

Comment: @domen Can u please take a look at this answer its another question I asked answered my own question just correct where it is wrong in comment. Can u please do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749351/in-order-to-write-pci-ethernet-driver-how-to-implement-mmap-in-the-pci-ethernet I just need to know now that how to access address of registers. is it /dev/mem+register-offset in mmap function of a device driver so do I need to maintain base address of dev/mem for pci device and keep it in global variable